# Insert sql by loop in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am still learning PHP. I am trying to get a value from input in HTML to insert new data into the database by loop and array. I am trying to set up flexible number of array that match columns. There is no error in PHP, but it could not insert into table. I think there is flaw program in

`foreach ($array as $row6)` area.

Can anyone help? Please forgive me, I'm Deaf, ASL is my primary language, english is my second language. Thank you for patient.

```
<!--doctype html-->
<html>
<head>
<title>Add name and number</title>
<link href="defaultdatabase.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<h2>Add any DSDJ information to database</h2>
<?php
require ("require2.php");

$sql = "show tables from XXXX";
$list = mysqli_query($GaryDB, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list)) {
    $table[] = $row[0];

    $option = '';

    foreach ($table as $rows) {
        $option .= "<option value='{$rows}'>{$rows}</option>";
    }
}

?>
<form action="addname.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr><th>Select the table</td><td>
        <select name="subject">
            <?php
            echo $option;
            ?>
        </select></td><td><input type="submit" name="selected" value="select"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<form>
<table>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['selected'])) {

    $selected = $_POST['subject'];

    $column = "select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = '" . $selected . "'";
    $list5 = mysqli_query($GaryDB, $column);

    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($list5)) {
        $input = '';
        foreach ($array as $row5) {
            $input = "<tr><td>{$row5}:</td><td colspan='2'><input type='text' name='{$row5}'></td></tr>";
        }
        echo $input;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {

        $array = mysqli_fetch_array($list5);
        $label = array();
            foreach($array as $row5) {
                $ins = "{$row5},";
            }
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($array as $row6) {
                    $label[$i] = $_POST['{$row6}'];
                    $value = implode("','",$label[$i]);
                    if ($label[$i]) {
                        $insert = "insert into " . $selected . "(" . $ins . ") values ('" . $label[$i]. "')";
                        mysqli_query($GaryDB, $insert);
                        echo "Successful insert in the Database";
                    } else {
                        echo "Fail to insert in the Database";
                    }
                }

    }echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='insert'></td></tr>";
}
mysqli_close($GaryDB);

?>

</table>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: echo out your $insert statement. This will show you your sql statement and hopefully why you are receiving the error(s).

Comment: Insert "echo (mysqli_error($con))" after the mysql query, where $con is your DB connection variable so you can have a look at the error code from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would take some time in naming your variables. It should help you and others read and make sense of your code.

```
if (isset($_POST['selected'])) {

   /* renamed variable from $selected to $table_name */
   $table_name = $_POST['subject']; 

  /* you can use variables inside double quotes */
  $column_name_sql = "select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = `$table_name`";

  /* renamed variable from $list5 to $result */
  $result = mysqli_query($GaryDB, $column_name_sql);

  /* Don't need the $input variable or the foreach, just output the table row. */
  while ($field_name = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$field_name}:</td><td colspan='2'><input type='text' name='{$field_name}'></td></tr>";
  }


  if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    /* reset the query result back to the first result */
    mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);

    $new_values = [];
    while ($field_name = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       $new_values[$field_name] = $_POST['{$field_name}'];
    }

    $insert_sql = "insert into `$table_name` (" . implode(',', array_keys($new_values)) . ") values ('" . implode(',', $new_values . "')";

    /* show the message based on the query result */
    if (mysqli_query($GaryDB, $insert_sql)) {
      echo "Successful insert in the Database";
    } else {
      echo "Fail to insert in the Database";
    }
    echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='insert'></td></tr>";
  }
  mysqli_close($GaryDB);
}
```

Another thing that I will say is be careful about adding data into the database, escaping the users input is required (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I tried your code, seem it doesn't work. I removed foreach, and use while in first place, it won't display as table name, just "array to string". I have to put foreach back to display it again. But the data didn't get in the database, even i put escape string, but still nothing. I did put mysqli_error message, but there is no error message. I suspect it is' database that block to insert...